# laravel blade snippets in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, laravel-blade, emmet

I installed and enabled laravel blade snippets but it does not work with Blade emmet in vs code but works well in controller and model
[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: Does it appear to be enabled when it comes to extension settings?

Comment: Yes and  I changed to true but ....

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same question in 2023...

Make sure you have enabled the extension for Blade files in your Settings

Open `Preferences` -> `Settings`

```
{
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true, // enable tab to expanse emmet tags
"blade.format.enable": true,         // if you would like to enable blade format
}
```